# How can I copy only files and folder created in the past hour in one directory to a new directory?

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste, robocopy, delete-file

Sorry, I have very little programming experience, but I'll try my best to make this make sense.

Basically, I want to create a program (a batch file possibly?) that runs every hour that deletes everything in the target directory, then copies any files or folders created in the past hour in the source directory to the target directory. Files and folders in the source directory should be unaffected. The deleting and copy functions could be two separate programs, if that makes things easier. They would just have to run in that order.

I've looked into a lot of different solutions, like Robocopy and xcopy, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make use of the /xo command in Robocopy without having anything in the target directory, and xcopy just doesn't seem to be able to accept this level of specificity.

Comment: Prior to posting I hadn't actually tried anything, because I have very little programming experience, particularly in this area. I had done a fair amount of research and was unable to find either an answer to my problem or enough answers that I could jury rig something together from.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set target=C:\The\Target Directory
set source=C:\The\Source Directory

rem Deletes everything in the target directory
echo Y | del "%target%" > NUL

rem Copies any files or folders created in the past hour in the source directory
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do set /A "oneHourAgo=(1%%a-101)*60+1%%b-100"

for %%a in ("%source%\*.*") do (
   for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=: " %%b in ("%%~Ta") do (
      set /A "fileTime=(1%%b-100)*60+1%%c-100"
      if "%%d" equ "p.m." (
         if %%b neq 12 (
            set /A fileTime+=12*60
         ) else (
            set /A fileTime-=12*60
         )
      )
   )
   if !fileTime! gtr !oneHourAgo! copy "%%a" "%target%"
)
```

This Batch file don't works correctly when the "last hour" pass over midnight. This point may be added, if required.

Comment: Okay, tested this out and not having any luck. I run the .bat file and nothing happens. Is it critical it be in a certain folder?

Comment: I tried changing source and target directories, as well as doing them with and without "" (they have spaces in them). I also tried making a log file but what it spit out I don't quite understand.

Here is the log file, with a few path edits. Note that there are 3 files and a folder in the source right now, and the one it found (file.txt) is the correct file. http://pastebin.com/0PUrPpEf

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy doesn't have the granularity, but XXcopy seems to handle it.

```
 /DA#30m selects files made within the last 30 minutes.
```

XXcopy is free for non commercial use and can be downloaded from http://www.xxcopy.com

XXcopy is xcopy on steroids.

Comment: This sounds like a viable option, but again, I probably don't have the programming know-how to actually make this work without a lot of guidance. I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: `xxcopy "c:\folder a\*.*" "D:\folder b\" /s /DA#60m`  something like that may be enough to copy the files and subdirectories that are less than 60 minutes old.

Comment: Robocopy can also do this using the /MINAGE or /MAXAGE options.

Comment: /minage:<N> Specifies the minimum file age (exclude files newer than N days or date). <---  It doesn't seem to accept minutes or hours, only days or a date.

Answer (score 0):

If the file names are predictable (which you do not say), I would write a simple logrotate script for Windows batch, like this one, and use windows task scheduler to run once per hour.  This script could be adjusted to make 3, 10, , 24, or more rotations.

```
@echo off
setlocal
CD logdir
del the.log.3
ren the.log.2 the.log.3
ren the.log.1 the.log.2
ren the.log.0 the.log.1
ren the.log the.log.0
```

Comment: Sorry names are not going to be predictable. I'm sure that would make things much easier >.<